# macのコマンドラインからGmailを送信する方法・手順を教えてください

Tags: macos, postfix, sendmail

macのコマンドラインから、以下ができるようにしたいのです。
・自分のgmailアドレスから他のgmailアドレスにメールを送信する

postfixを起動してコマンドラインから以下コマンドでmail送信を試してみましたが、うまく送信できませんでした。
 date | mail -s test mailtest@gmail.com

/var/log/mail.logに以下ログが出ます。
Apr 27 11:56:27 xxxx-xx-MacBook-Air postfix/error[15630]: XXXXXXXXXX: to=, relay=none, delay=68742, delays=68739/3.5/0/0, dsn=4.7.8, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: SASL authentication failed; server smtp.gmail.com[74.125.203.109] said: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at?535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257

以下に書かれていることは確認しました。
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257

postfixは下記ファイルに追記しました。
＊追記したファイル
/private/etc/postfix/main.cf

＊追記内容
＃ Posifix Configuratoins
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587

＃ SASL Authentication
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/gmail_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain

＃ TLS Settings
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

＃tls setting
smtp_use_tls = yes

よろしくお願いします

Comment: 実際に実行したコマンドをのせて下さい．

Comment: いろんな原因が考えられますがご質問の内容からそれを推測するのは難しいですね。既にコメントで指摘されてますがご自身が行った内容を省略せずに質問に追記してみてください。ヘルプセンターには質問の[ガイドライン](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)があります。是非こちらをご覧になって質問の内容を「編集」してみてください。そうすれば回答が付きやすくなりますよ。

Comment: >takoikaさん
実行したコマンドを記載しました。
>take88さん
postfixの設定など追記しました。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージで参照するよう提示されてるURLにも書いてありますが、ID、パスワードが間違っていないのであれば、

- (二段階認証を有効にしていない場合)「安全性の低いアプリのアクセスを許可」がされていない
- (二段階認証を有効にしている場合)アプリパスワードを使用していないか間違っている

に引っかかっているのだと思います

Answer (score -1):

Gmailは最近、OAuthというSSLの上位(?)認証を導入し、
いろいろなところでトラブルが出たり対応されたりしています。

ソコが関係してないでしょうか。

的外れでしたらすいません。